# How do I get all music off my iPhone without losing my audiobooks?

Tags: iphone, itunes, music, itunes-match

I never purchased any music and am not subscribed to iTunes Match. Everything in settings is set to "no" or "off". I have unwanted, unpurchased music and want to get it off my iPhone. However, I have two audiobooks, sync'd through iTunes from my computer, that I do not want to lose. I have to ask Seri to open them, because I have no Audiobook section and can't find them otherwise.

Comment: You could manually delete the unwanted music files

Comment: Connect your iPhone to iTunes on your Mac and you should be able to delete only what you want.

Answer (score 1):

As John Ramos said, you should sync your iPhone with iTunes on your computer, at which point you should have the option to sync audiobooks but *not* music.